# Vertical line between 2 field in css

Tags: html, css

I wanna separate 2 field with a long vertical line.

```
link1 | abc
link2 | abc
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @user3027246, add a solution.

Answer (score 1):

So you want link 1 link2 on one side, and abc abc on the other, separated by a vertical line?

You can wrap the two links in a div and give it a

```
 border-left:1px solid black;
```

Or you can use a table and give the td cells a border.

Or you can use an empty div(with some border) with zero width, and auto height, and put it between the two to separate them.

(Personally, I'd go with the first one)

Update: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/V5VH2/1/)

Comment: I've tried it but in the right side, content like "abc" is in other line. I want link1 and content "abc" in the same line

Comment: Check the fiddle that I've added. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're really want to do but you can do sth similar with border on the "abc" divs

```
border-left: 1px solid black;
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/YNp6r/)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

divide your fields in two `div`. and then add a `right border to left` div **OR** `left boarder to right` div

to declare my explanation i wrote a sample code:

**HTML**

```
<div class='left'>
   <p>link1</p>
   <p>link2</p>
</div>
<div class='right'>
   <p>abs</p>
   <p>akdas</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left{
   display: inline-block;
   border-right: 1px #F05940 solid;
}
.right{
   display: inline-block;   
}
```

---

you can devide your general div in 3 part
(any part is an div)

- first div for links
- second one is for an image that'a an vertical line
- and third one is an abc!

or you can use semantic-ui to do that easily
see this link
   http://semantic-ui.com/elements/divider.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your links in one div and abcs in another div, this will separate the two fields. Then use a divider and set your own margins to fit in-between the two divs:

```
<div class='left'>
   <p>link1</p>
   <p>link2</p>
</div>

<div class='right'>
   <p>abc1</p>
   <p>abc2</p>
</div>

.divider{
    position:absolute;
    left:#%;
    top:#%;
    bottom:#%;
    border-left:1px solid black;
}
```